# chrome.Event is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

Since las Chrome Update (72.0.3626.119 (Build oficial) (64 bits) I get this error on a Chrome Extension

> chrome.Event is not a constructor

This is the full project: https://github.com/avalero/bitbloq-chromeapp . This is happening on line 11 of https://github.com/avalero/bitbloq-chromeapp/blob/master/app/lib/serial.js :

```
this.onConnect = new chrome.Event();
```

Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Can you use the immediate window to investigate what chrome.Event is? Be interesting to see what comes up.

Comment: `chrome.Event` is not documented and thus not guaranteed to be supported. If you think you can convince Chromium developers they should fix it, consider reporting it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: FWIW you can probably construct it directly `new chrome.runtime.onMessage.constructor()`